# Infinitely many squares in a sequence.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

In the sequence of integers $a, a+d, a + 2d, a + 3d, ... $

$a,d> 0$

How to prove that if one of the numbers is a square, than there are infinitely many squares in the sequence ?

Comment: You mean $b = d$?

Comment: @ Don Larynx : thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $b^2$ is any square and any $d > 0$ is given, then for any $n > 0$, $$b^2 + (dn^2+2nb)d = (b+dn)^2$$ is also a square.

Comment: I think $ (b+dn)^2 = b^2+2bnd+d^2n^2= b^2+d(dn^2+2bn)$. Aside from that typo of leaving out that $b$, this is correct and clever.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks, I forgot the $b$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  WLOG let $a$ be a square.  Then can you show $(\sqrt{a}+d)^2$ appears in the sequence?